# Running an executable GUI from Python while running script in background

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have a potentially simple problem that I need to solve. 
In essence, I'm attempting to open a .exe file (it's a statistical software package for machine learning analysis). As users are creating models and simulations in the package, I want Python to continuously search for output files for further manipulation.

Here is my code so far:

```
import threading
import subprocess
from time import sleep

SPM_RUNNING = False

def run_spm():
  subprocess.call("SOFTWARE.EXE")
  SPM_RUNNING = False # When SPM finished.


SPM_RUNNING = True
t = threading.Thread(target=run_spm)
t.start()

while SPM_RUNNING:
    # This will be replaced with the actual manipulations 
    print "This program is running"
```

The problem is that the .exe file opens up, but the next part of the code does not continue to run until AFTER the .exe file is closed. I would like the code to run WHILE it is open.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The only mistake I see in the example code is that you didn't declare `SPM_RUNNING` as global inside the `run_spm` function:

```
import threading
import subprocess
from time import sleep

SPM_RUNNING = False

def run_spm():
  global SPM_RUNNING  # You forgot this.
  subprocess.call("SOFTWARE.EXE")
  SPM_RUNNING = False # When SPM finished.


SPM_RUNNING = True
t = threading.Thread(target=run_spm)
t.start()

while SPM_RUNNING:
    # This will be replaced with the actual manipulations 
    print "This program is running"
```

Without that declaration, the `SPM_RUNNING` variable you're setting to `False` in `run_spm` is only created in the local scope; the global `SPM_RUNNING` doesn't change.

Other than that, it looks fine. I made an almost identical script on my Linux box:

```
import threading
import subprocess
from time import sleep

SPM_RUNNING = False

def run_spm():
  global SPM_RUNNING
  subprocess.call(["sleep", "10"])
  SPM_RUNNING = False # When SPM finished.


SPM_RUNNING = True
t = threading.Thread(target=run_spm)
t.start()

while SPM_RUNNING:
    print("running")
    sleep(1)
print('done')
```

Here's the output:

```
running
running
running
running
running
running
running
running
running
running
done
```

Which is exactly what you'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

You might try passing the DETACHED_PROCESS flag when on Windows.

```
DETACHED_PROCESS = 0x00000008

process_id = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "software.exe"],creationflags=DETACHED_PROCESS).pid
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help here. Actually, the problem was still coming up - what ended up working was moving to the os.startfile command instead. subprocess.call and os.system were locking up Python, and even with the threading command, didn't work. This was probably due to the particular nature of the GUI that I was trying to open up.

Anyways - I used os.startfile, and then looped in a test command that looked for instances of that program running.. when that function determined the program was no longer running, it initiated the sys.exit() function to close down the script.

Thanks again